# objective-c excessive cpu utilization dispatching to main thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cpu

I'm performing a somewhat CPU intensive operation (TensorFlow model inference)on a background thread.  However, it isn't until I interrupt the main thread that it appears the CPU utilization is realized.  For example:

```
//process model on background thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

        ModelData* data =  [_processor processData:image];
        
        //now process the results on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           [self processData:data];

          });
        });
```

[self processData:data] isn't doing anything expensive at all and nothing I would expect to spike the processor.  More interesting is if I remove the main thread processing all together (and only interrupt the main thread to do nothing) the CPU still sees excessive CPU utilization.  For example:

```
//process model on background thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    ModelData* data =  [_processor processData:image];
    
    //now process the results on the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

       //do nothing, only interrupt the main thread

      });
    });
```

If I remove the call to dispatch to the main thread, I see no excessive CPU utilization at all.  For example:

```
//process model on background thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    ModelData* data =  [_processor processData:image];
)};
```

So it appears that just dispatching to the main thread rails the CPU.
Any idea why this is happening?  Thanks!!

Comment: Interesting. How do you know this is happening? What's your metrics harness?

Comment: Using the debugger it shows me the CPU utilization.  Also, from the seat of the pants perspective, just having the call to dispatch to the main queue creates a very choppy user experience.  If I remove that call.  Smooth.

Comment: 1. Did you try to instrument your application? 2. Does this happen without the TensorFlow, i.e. by changing TensorFlow call to something like `for (int i = 0; i < 0xffffffff; i++) { int j = i * i * i * i; }` ?

Comment: Good idea.  If I do that I see high CPU utilization like I would expect (even without dispatching to main queue).   It must be something specific to tensor flow.  I'll have dig deeper.

Comment: Don't believe the debugger graph. Use real metrics. You can do that with XCTMetrics or with Instruments. Even logging simple print statements would be better than just looking at the debugger graph.